# TYPO3 different rights on different subtrees in same site for same user

Tags: typo3, workspace, group, rights

We have a group of editors that have to edit in “live mode” a subtree in our site and have to edit in “draft mode only” another subtree of the same site.

Is it possible? All my tests suggest that rights are additive… Our 2 subtrees have different user groups with appropriate rights and our editor group inherit both groups.

How can we manage that kind of configuration?

Thanks!

**Settings**
Subtree A: access permission to group A with live editing enabled
Subtree B: access permission to group B without live editing enabled (has to use the workflow)
User X: inherit both group A and B

**Expected**
User X can edit and publish live in subtree A
User X cannot edit and publish live in subtree A and can only use workspace (workflow) to edit in subtree B.

**Results**
User X can edit and publish live in subtree A and B

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. I see 2 solutions here:

- 1st: Use 2 different users
- 2nd: Hook/Xclass into BackendUserAuthentication and return the permissions based on current pages (which might be impossible on some situations, e.g. when no page is given)